# Sweet.js: Possible to expand a JS object into a JS object?

Tags: macros, sweet.js

Is it possible to use Sweet.Js to expand

```
{ "foo": "bar" }
```

to

```
{ "bar": "foo" }
```

for example?

My naïve attempt [here](http://goo.gl/O5Trqw) doesn’t work and I don’t see an example in the [documentation](http://sweetjs.org/doc/main/sweet.html).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is that `:` has special meaning in patterns so you need to escape it with `$[:]`

```
macro bar {
  rule { {$x $[:] $y} } =>  { {$y: $x} }
}

var o = bar { "bax": "quux" }
```

Comment: To try this (and a few other examples), I pasted your code into the editor at http://sweetjs.org/browser/editor.html, and hit "Compile". But I get this error: `Error: [assertion error]: cannot get the val of a delimiter`. How do I use this?